# Make letters from a word bold based on user input

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs

I have a search component in my app and when the user input some texts it filters data based on the user input and shows a list of filtered data. What i want to do is to make the text that is searched by the user bold in the filtered data. So for example if i search 'Jo' , the filtered data should show as **Jo**hn / **Jo**seph / **Jo**e Rogan

i can figure out a way to make the entire word bold but cannot figure out a way to bold only the part where user typed.

Comment: Please show us what you have so far and we'll try to update it to meet your requirements :)

Answer (score 1):

You want to change how each string in the filtered data is rendered, based on the search term.

You can use the search term to create a regex, then add `<strong>` tags to each string based on the regex.

If you don't want to use `dangerouslySetInnerHtml` then you can do something like this:

```
const data = ["John", "Banjo", "Jojo", "Bob Jones", "John Johnson", "James"];

const searchTerm = "jo";

const searchTermRegex = new RegExp(
  // Escape special regex characters in the search term,
  // otherwise you will get an invalid regex
  `(${searchTerm.replace(/[.\\+*?[^\]$(){}=!<>|:-]/g, "\\$&")})`,
  "gi"
);

const getBoldFilteredText = (text, term) => {
  const substrings = text.split(searchTermRegex);
  return (
    <div>
      {substrings.map((substring) =>
        substring.toLowerCase() === term.toLowerCase() ? (
          <strong>{substring}</strong>
        ) : (
          substring
        )
      )}
    </div>
  );
};

return <div>{data.map((s) => getBoldFilteredText(s, searchTerm))}</div>;
```

Comment: This answer solves the problem of how to render partially bold text in React. You can take this example and implement it into your app. I am not going to write out filtering logic, fetch logic, and build a complete component for you because you haven't provided any code in your question. It is quite obvious that the search term would simply be your state value that changes from user input, and you would filter data before rendering it.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a way of doing it that *doesn't* use `dangerouslySetInnerHTML` or open you up to XSS attacks.

Explanation: `String#split` with a regex capturing group (`/(...)/`) includes the captured text in the results at odd-numbered indexes. For example, `'baba'.split(/(b)/)` gives you `["", "b", "a", "b", "a"]`. Once you have these results, you can map the odd (matched) results to `strong` elements and the even ones to `React.Fragment`s.

[Demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/undangerous-n0shu?file=/src/App.js:346-1021)

```
// https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions#Escaping
const regexEscape = str => str.replace(/[.*+\-?^${}()|[\]\\]/g, '\\$&')

const boldify = searchStr => targetStr => {
  return targetStr
    .split(new RegExp(`(${regexEscape(searchStr)})`, 'i'))
    .map((part, idx) =>
      idx % 2 ? (
        <strong key={idx}>{part}</strong>
      ) : (
        <React.Fragment key={idx}>{part}</React.Fragment>
      )
    )
}

const SearchForm = () => {
  const [searchStr, setSearchStr] = useState('');

  return (
    <form onSubmit={e => e.preventDefault()}>
      <input
        type='text'
        value={searchStr}
        onChange={e => setSearchStr(e.currentTarget.value)}
      />

      <ul>
        {list.map(item => {
          return <li>{boldify(searchStr)(item)}</li>;
        })}
      </ul>
    </form>
  )
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Pretty simple. Just split and join with bold or strong tag.

```
let searchStr = "Jo"
name.split(searchStr ).join('<b>'+ searchStr +'</b>');
```

```js
let searchStr = "Jo";
let name = "John";

document.getElementById('res').innerHTML = name.split(searchStr).join('<b>'+ searchStr +'</b>');
```

```html
<h2>Searching "Jo" in John</h2>
<p id="res"></p>
```

Comment: You don't want to do innerHTML mangling in React though.

Comment: It is just for the demo in vanilla JS, not in react. Logic is same for both. He just needs the logic to insert Bold tags. Everyone knows to use `dangerouslySetInnerHTML` to set a HTML content in react.

Comment: Why would you want to use `dangerouslySetInnerHTML` for this? The clue is in the title. And this question explicitly mentions that it's arbitrary user input.

Comment: Please see this example, why we need `dangerouslySetInnerHTML` - https://codesandbox.io/s/react-hooks-search-filter-4gnwc?file=/src/index.js . This is exactly what he wants.

Comment: @Prem Until OP wants to search with a term (or show a result) that does actually have HTML markup and `dangerouslySetInnerHTML` veers into dangerous territory.

Comment: @Prem That example shows that one possible solution uses `dangerouslySetInnerHTML`. It doesn't show that `dangerouslySetInnerHTML` is required (because it's not).